Cucumber feature file: How can I pass variables in a data table
Is there a way I can pass variables defined in a previous step, in the data table of a feature file?
I have a scenario with:
Then database content is
      | serviceName           | timesSet                                 |
      | a_random_service_1    | [0, <my_variable_1>, <my_variable_2>]    |
      | a_random_service_2    | [0]                                      |
      | a_random_service_3    | [0]                                      |


I want to fetch my_variable_1 and my_variable_2 from my code (these are defined at runtime). I have tried using ERB but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

It sounds like you're trying to program in Gherkin. This usually makes features too complex to be understood by non-programmers. So if only technical people read your features, consider writing tests in a programming language. If non-technical people do read your features, try excluding non-essential details and store those in the class fields of your step definitions.

I assume you want to pass multiple timeset to a specific service if that's the case you can do this (the code is in JavaScript) but logic will be the same.
|serviceName|timeSet|
|ServiceA||10,20,30|
|ServiceB|44,67,69|


function(serviceName,timeSet){
let timeArray;
if(timeSet.includes(','){
timeArray=timeSet.split(',')// timeArray will contain timeSet like [10,20,30]
}
}

In this way you can get the array of timeSet which you are trying to pass through timeSet
timeArray variable contains your variables in array which you can use further in service

Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this is what I'm trying to do.  I don't know at runtime what is the value of my variable (it will be a timestamp), and this is what I'm trying to get to: I can define variable_1 and variable_2 in my code, but how can I then call them in my feature file data table?

You can store those variables which you defined in previous step in a JSON file and then use the values from JSON file in the next step at runtime. Simply read the data from JSON file whenever those variables are required
